# Why does my GET function replaces an object in a map as opposed to adding the object to the end of the map?

Tags: java, rest, dictionary, get

I'm trying to add a user to a map via query parameters in the url. The GET function in my java class passes the parameters into the user constructor and updates the map, it also increments an ID variable, it then returns a list of the objects. The problem is when I repeat the process above the object is replaced as opposed to being added.

```
      //Map Declaration
      private static Map<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<Integer, User>();

      .....


      @GET
      @Path("/adduser")
      public List<User> adduser(
         @QueryParam("username") String username,
         @QueryParam("password") String password){

      User user = new User();

      user.setId(users.size() +1);
      user.setUsername(username);
      user.setPassword(password);

      users.put(user.getId(), user);

      return new ArrayList<User>(users.values());
 }
```

Comment: The real question is, why is a GET method adding users? That's not RESTful.

Comment: because it is retrieving values from the client side, and GET requests include all required data in the URL no?

Comment: As silly as it sounds, have you checked that setId and getId are working?

Comment: Depends how to "repeate the process". If it is done concurrently you can end up with multiple `User` objects having same id.

Comment: GET requests _get_ things. They don't add things (that's what POST is for) or update things (the meaning of PUT). At least not in REST.

Comment: For some reason it decided to work today, i didnt change any code? Thanks for the replys